# allow more than 15 digits number in excel cell

Tags: asp.net, export-to-excel

how to allow entering more than 15 digits in excel cell while exporting data to excel in .NET

Comment: is the limitation of .NET?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the cell reference and change it's format to Number.

C# example;

```
myRange.NumberFormat = "0.0";
```